# Using generics in lambda expression or how to access a dbset with generics

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I'm developing a Test project with NUnit, Moq, C# and .NET Framework 4.7.

I have these two methods that are almost equals:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

private void MockProducts(Mock<TRZFDbContext> mockContext, List<Product> data)
{
    IQueryable<Product> queryable = data.AsQueryable();

    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Product>>();

    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Product>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Product>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Product>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Product>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => queryable.GetEnumerator());
    mockSet.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<Product>())).Callback<Product>((s) => data.Add(s));
    mockSet.Setup(d => d.Remove(It.IsAny<Product>())).Callback<Product>((s) => data.Remove(s));

    mockContext.Setup(m => m.Product).Returns(mockSet.Object);
}

private void MockEmvoProducts(Mock<TRZFDbContext> mockContext, List<EmvoProduct> data)
{
    IQueryable<EmvoProduct> queryable = data.AsQueryable();

    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<EmvoProduct>>();

    mockSet.As<IQueryable<EmvoProduct>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<EmvoProduct>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<EmvoProduct>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<EmvoProduct>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => queryable.GetEnumerator());
    mockSet.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<EmvoProduct>())).Callback<EmvoProduct>((s) => data.Add(s));
    mockSet.Setup(d => d.Remove(It.IsAny<EmvoProduct>())).Callback<EmvoProduct>((s) => data.Remove(s));

    mockContext.Setup(m => m.EmvoProduct).Returns(mockSet.Object);
}
```

I can create a generics method changing the second argument `data` with a generic. But my problem is on the last sentence:

```
mockContext.Setup(m => m.Product).Returns(mockSet.Object);
```

and

```
mockContext.Setup(m => m.EmvoProduct).Returns(mockSet.Object);
```

`m.Product` is a DbSet of `Product` and `m.EmvoProduct` is a DbSet of `EmvoProduct`.

Is there a way to make the lambda expression uses the generics? Or maybe there are another approaches.

Comment: basically you want to create the function setup?

Comment: Yes. But the question is how to make it generics. Maybe I have to move the latest sentence outside like they did here: https://www.rhyous.com/2015/04/10/how-to-mock-an-entity-framework-dbcontext-and-its-dbset-properties/

Comment: which line number in the link?

Comment: line 31. Method MockDbSet: it is almost the same method that I have but without the last sentence. But I don't understand MockTables method.

Comment: yep... my answer should work for the function defined in line 31. Basically the `Setup` function can use the from with generic type T, since the the DbSet is defined as DbSet<T>

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do so with an extension function that is declared something like this in a **public static class**

```
public static class DBSetExtensions {

    public static void Setup<T>(this DbSet<T> list, Action<T> lamda){
        lamda(objectFromDbSet);
    }

}
```

Now in any class you have a DbSet with generics you should be able to use

```
mockSet.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<EmvoProduct>()))
```

For the chained function `Callback`, you need to change the return type on the function above from void to whatever object they return in setup.

Comment: Could you please add an example about how to use your answer? Thanks.

Comment: I have updated it. As long as it is a static function it will work everywhere you use a DBSet object